# fbx file asks for fbm file in xna?

Tags: xna, models, blender

I downloaded a bat model from the internet and I went to Blender, used texture and shading as I want, then I exported it as a fbx file. Next I placed it into my content pipeline and ran it but it is asking me for the path of a .fbm file. It says Error Missing asset

> C: ...._Game\obj\x86\Debug\FBX\387D35A3\bat.fbm\wpn_fps_mel_barbedwire_df.dds

What does this mean. How can I place these images in that file like that?

Comment: added the file path and it created every thing automatically. Then I just put the images in there and it all worked out.

Comment: there are no other export types to try ? maybe .obj would work ?